# custom Angular component not applying css class on ie11

Tags: css, angular, internet-explorer, sass

I have a component such as:

```
<my-component></my-component>
```

I want to give this component a

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

I tried:

```
<my-component class="ofx-hidden"></my-component>
.ofx-hidden {overflow-x: hidden;}
```

but class just doesn't appear in the debugger. it does appear for other browsers

I tried:

```
<my-component style="overflow-x: hidden;"></my-component>
```

also not working, just not showing up in the dom

I tried:

```
<my-component></my-component>
```

and

```
:host {overflow-x: hidden;}
```

inside the my-component.scss file

Nothing seems to work, What can i do or what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it was not properly  flushing the cache. any of the above worked after flushing cache. FML.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.